# Datetime indicator shows times for unrequested locations

Tags: 12.04, indicator, time

I am from India , so I have added my time locations in time settings .

I have added only one location, but the indicator is showing other locations which I have not added to list. (See the screenshot.)

Why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply should not be happening.

But you are not the only person to experience this sort of problem: [Bug #918067](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/918067), [Bug #996623](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/996623), [Bug #996845](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/996845).

If you do not feel the above bugs are the same issue you are seeing, you could report your own bug by running `ubuntu-bug indicator-datetime`.

Comment: i have reported .